# Report Filter Date

Tags: reporting, date, custom, filters

I am looking to filter a date to show appointment dates for only this month to todays date (so not the entire month). Is there a relative date formula i can use for this?

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your filter as it is, and try adding a second filter on the same field with `less or equal` as the operator and `TODAY` as the relative date.

Comment: great thank you this worked